# Json postgresql 9.4

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have tried and facing issue while reading json column in PostgreSQL table. below is the table description.

```
task=# \d quots                                           
       Table "public.quots"
      Column      |  Type   | Modifiers 
------------------+---------+-----------
 items            | json    | 
 id               | integer | 
 supplier_id      | integer |
```

Here is the data in table.

```
select items from quots limit 1;
                                                    items
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"item1":[{"id":5,"name":"Item Name","unitPrice":{"original":10.0,"converted":10.0}}],"item2":{"id":75,"name":"Name"},"id":23653}]
```

Now when I try to query and get item1, it return empty.

```
select items->'item1' from quots limit 1;
 ?column? 
----------

(1 row)
```

Any Clue?

PostgreSQL 9.4.4
PSQL 9.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json value is an array. You can select its first element using `items->0`:

```
select items->0->'item1' from quots limit 1;

                                   ?column?                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id":5,"name":"Item Name","unitPrice":{"original":10.0,"converted":10.0}}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: When I try to use array_to_json(items->0->'item1') it returns. ERROR:  cannot deconstruct an array as an object

Comment: I can not help you without seeing the context. Ask a new question containing data causing the error.